# Kafka Streams stops listening from topic and processing messages when broker goes down

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a 2 Kafka Streams application. One application listens from say `topic1` and produces to `topic2` and the other listens from `topic2` and produces to `topic3`. The applications were working fine before the kafka broker went down. The broker came back up but the streams applications have stopped.

**Following is the exception of first streams app:**

```
Exception in thread "streams-collection-7cda47bc-a1db-4ad5-a3d4-bd8f8dc85bf4-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in process. taskId=0_0, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000, topic=o365_activity_contenturl, partition=0, offset=2151
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:232)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.process(AssignedTasks.java:403)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:317)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.processAndMaybeCommit(StreamThread.java:942)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:822)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:774)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: task [0_0] Abort sending since an error caught with a previous record (key null value {"RecordType":6,"ListId":"affd3b1e-5d16-4e36-b97a-871b755b2b40","Version":1,"SourceFileName":"9617","ClientIP":"94.245.89.59","Workload":"OneDrive","UserType":0} timestamp 1527845926991) to topic o365_user_activity due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 15 record(s) for topic1-0: 32551 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl$1.onCompletion(RecordCollectorImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.completeFutureAndFireCallbacks(ProducerBatch.java:204)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.done(ProducerBatch.java:187)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.failBatch(Sender.java:627)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.sendProducerData(Sender.java:287)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:238)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 15 record(s) for topic1-0: 32551 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
```

**Exception of second streams app:**

```
Exception in thread "streams-distribution-bf0d8698-f198-4d91-ad66-f0833b4ef398-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: task [0_0] Abort sending since an error caught with a previous record (key null value {"item_type":"File","workload":"OneDrive","current_date":"2018-06-01","client_ip":"94.245.89.59"} timestamp 1527845926986) to topic topic3 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 3 record(s) for topic3-0: 34706 ms has passed since last attempt plus backoff time.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl$1.onCompletion(RecordCollectorImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.completeFutureAndFireCallbacks(ProducerBatch.java:204)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.done(ProducerBatch.java:187)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.failBatch(Sender.java:627)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.sendProducerData(Sender.java:287)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:238)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 3 record(s) for topic3-0: 34706 ms has passed since last attempt plus backoff time
```

Why does streams application fails to recover?

**UPDATE 1:**

After updating from Kafka `1.0.0` to `1.1.0`, I have an additional information in the log:

```
You can increase producer parameter `retries` and `retry.backoff.ms` to avoid this error.
```

Streams app still doesn't continue processing after I stop the broker and restart it.

**UPDATE 2:**

However when I restart streams app itself, after stopping and starting the kafka broker, it starts consuming.

**Configs:**

```
props.put(StreamsConfig.RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, 100000);
props.put(StreamsConfig.RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MAX_MS_CONFIG, 200000);
props.put(StreamsConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 60000);
props.put(StreamsConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, 60000);
props.put(StreamsConfig.producerPrefix(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG), true);
props.put(StreamsConfig.producerPrefix(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG), "all");
```

Comment: Hard to say. What version do you use? Have to tried to bounce the application instances?

Comment: I am using `version 1.0.0`

Comment: Only the log message was changed in 1.1.0 -- you can increase both configs in 1.0, too and it should make stream resilient against broker restarts. Both configs must be set such that broker restart finished before retires are exhausted.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Are these `ProducerConfigs` or `StreamConfigs`?

Comment: Before 1.1.0 release, it was only a producer config. Since 1.1.0 it's both (cf. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-224%3A+Add+configuration+parameter+%60retries%60+to+Streams+API)

Comment: But when I add this `props.put(StreamsConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 1);` I get `RETRIES_CONFIG cannot be resolved or is not a field`. I can however put `RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG` in StreamsConfig.

Comment: And do I need to change these configs for both Streams and Producer to avoid the error?

Comment: Those variables don't exist in `1.0.x` -- but you can just pass in the strings `"retries"` and "`retry.backoff.ms"` directly. Or use the `ProducerConfig` variables. The vars a just for convenience. Internally, everything is base on strings.

Comment: Is the issue resolved via increasing retries? What configs did you specify?

Comment: I have updated the question to include configs. One thing I noticed with the above configs is that if I produce single message after some intervals (a couple of seconds) then streams app doesn't throws any exception. However, when producing messages in bulk I get the same exception. I think I should try one config at a time and see how streams app behaves.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Are there any recommended configs for streams app to make it resilient against broker failures?

Comment: You should also increase `retries`.