# How to properly configure Kafka Stream to ensure brokers resiliency?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Recently I tried to ensure my Kafka Streams (2.0.0 version) application will still be up and running (streams will resume) after any of the Kafka brokers will go up after unspecified downtime of all of the brokers (downtime more like few hours than few seconds).

It did not come up with default configuration (`retries` on 0) since after all brokers have been killed, all my streams changed state to `ERROR` or even `DEAD` and stopped working:

```
INFO  o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [MyStream-0936f6a6-c9f4-4591-9b25-534abc65b8d1-StreamThread-24] State transition from RUNNING to PENDING_SHUTDOWN
```

and then:

```
INFO  o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [MyStream-0936f6a6-c9f4-4591-9b25-534abc65b8d1-StreamThread-24] State transition from PENDING_SHUTDOWN to DEAD
```

And some of the streams went asap to ERROR:

```
stream-client [MyStream-88a8fe9a-d565-43e3-acb5-20cccc6b4a88] State transition from RUNNING to ERROR
```

As a result, considering state transition (https://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/2.0.0/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.State.html) I can't resume in any other way than restarting application.

What I did found was this topic:
[Kafka Streams stops listening from topic and processing messages when broker goes down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50674427/kafka-streams-stops-listening-from-topic-and-processing-messages-when-broker-goe)

It answers my question with advice to increase my streams `retries` as well as `retry.backoff.ms` config. This is what I did (increased `retries` to `Int.MaxNumber` and `retry.backoff.ms` to `1000`) and found out that there are some performance issues with this approach and I happened to get recurring error in logs: `FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND` which I cannot really found information about.

Are there any other ways of achieving brokers resiliency than increasing retries number? I can accept some of the messages lost after Kafka Brokers failure and I don't really need to retry if a message cannot be produced/consumed. I was thinking of manually restarting the stream after broker failure, but I'm not really sure how to catch the "broker down exception", what do you think?

These is my streams config:

```
buffered.records.per.partition = 1000
cache.max.bytes.buffering = 10485760
commit.interval.ms = 30000
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
default.key.serde = ... Serdes$StringSerde
default.production.exception.handler = ... DefaultProductionExHandler
default.timestamp.extractor = ... FailOnInvalidTimestamp
default.value.serde = ... Serdes$StringSerde
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
num.standby.replicas = 0
num.stream.threads = 8
partition.grouper = ... DefaultPartitionGrouper
poll.ms = 100
processing.guarantee = at_least_once
receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
replication.factor = 1
request.timeout.ms = 40000
retries = 0
retry.backoff.ms = 1000
rocksdb.config.setter = null
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
state.cleanup.delay.ms = 600000
state.dir = /tmp/kafka-state
topology.optimization = all
upgrade.from = null
windowstore.changelog.additional.retention.ms = 86400000
```

Answer (score 0):

Increasing retries is the correct way to handle broker downtime.

I am not sure, why increasing number of retries would have a performance impact though. Can you elaborate on this?

Besides this, there is nothing like a "broker down exception". You can register an uncaught exception handler in `KafkaStream` instance. It informs you about dying thread, and thus, you can react to it, by restarting the `KafkaStreams` client.

You could also try to change the `production.exception.handler` and skip over some production errors. Note, that you might loose all buffered message in the client for this case. (Also note, that you cannot skip all errors with the handler -- some errors are consider FATAL and `KafkaStreams` will shut down, regardless of you config.)

Comment: I'm continuously getting this error in Kafka "FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND", wanted to understand implication.

Comment: This should be a retryable consumer error, and thus should only be logged as a WARNING.